# Как можно получить рандомные id без повторений в sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Как можно получить рандомные id без повторений в sequelize?

```
const getAllItems = async (page) => {
    return await Items.findAll({
        order: [
            ['id', 'DESC'] <===== ?
        ],
        limit: 9,
        offset: 9 * page,
    })
};
```

Чтобы на выходе при каждом запросе у мне приходил массив 9 элементов из случайно выбранных итемов , которые не повторяются с предыдущими , запросов может быть несколько пока не закончится итемы

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42146200/selecting-a-random-record-from-sequelize-findall

Comment: @AzizUmarov не подойдёт. у него пагинированный запрос, так что при запросе 2рой страницы не будет "применён" порядок запроса первой страницы

Comment: @nörbörnën да я об этом думал. Можно рандомно получить все id затем по странично получать сами объекты.

Comment: @AzizUmarov не очень понимаю как)

Comment: рандом может мне вернуть например 1,1,1,2,3,1 и на второй странице может повторится, а мне нужно 1,3,5,7 при другом запросе 2,4,6,8,9

Comment: По этой причине вы получите только ID а сами объекты нет. Затем постранично берите только нужные объекты

Comment: Рандом вернет только 1,3,67,16,25,37, ... потом постранично List{ {id=1, name= ...}, {id=3, name ...}}